# Who first used complex analysis to account for singularities in field theory?

Tags: theoretical-physics, mathematical-physics

In 1925, Frenkel wrote a paper titled [Zur Elektrodynamik punktförmiger Elektronen](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01331692), which used complex analysis to treat an electron as a point, and its corresponding potential function as an isolated singularity at its position; hence eliminating the problems of an infinite self-energy and further problems for an extended electron with an internal structure. For me, the idea is profoundly elegant and simple, yet the paper is currently only cited by 57 other papers, which suggests to me that Frenkel may not have been the first to use this technique.

If not Frenkel, who was the first to use complex analysis to deal with isolated singularities in field theory?

Comment: Checking what Felix Klein did with Kummer surfaces perhaps.

Comment: The problem with avoiding the sigularity is that it eliminates the particle itself too, thereby advancing a litterally empty view on particles. An intern structure approach seems more reasonable.